# Using a Java SOAP service breaks javax.mail's quoted printable mail encapsulation

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, jakarta-mail, quoted-printable

This has had me puzzled for many hours, and seems inherently unlikely, but please bear with me; I believe I have proof.

I have simplified this down to a minimal test case (below). To test the code, you will need to use `EmailTest.java` (below), then import a SOAP service. To do this I used:

```
wsimport -d bin -s src -keep -extension 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl'
```

For convenience I've also put the code on github [here](https://github.com/abligh/emailtest), so you can simply clone it and run it; this has the `wsimport` already performed.

What the code below does is as follows:

- calls `testMime()`, which creates a `quoted-printable` part, then displays it correctly (with top bit set characters escaped with sequences beginning with `=`);
- calls `stockQuoteTest`, which simply gets a new web service entry point - it need not actually call the web service;
- calls `testMime()` again, which creates a `quoted-printable` part, but displays it incorrectly, not escaping the characters; `system.out.Println` then (predictably) replaces them with `?`.

I've used multiple SOAP libraries all of which do the same thing - I picked a simple demo one to demonstrate. It is not necessary actually to call the SOAP endpoint. The call to `getPort` (here in `getStockQuoteSoap12`) appears to be the problem.

My debugging so far has determined that none of the default Java encodings I know about have changed, and that the problem appears to be that on the second call the `quoted-printable` encoder never gets called. This appears to be because `part.dh.dataContentHandler` gets set to something of type `ObjectDataContentHandler` when it works, and of type `StringDataContentHandler` when it doesn't work.

Any ideas on what is going on here or how to fix it?

I'm using `javax.mail` 1.5.2 (the newest, but but an older version was the same) - and

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Here's `EmailTest.java`

```
package emailtest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

// use any SOAP service. This one was generated using
//   wsimport -d bin -s src -keep -extension http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl
import net.webservicex.StockQuote;
import net.webservicex.StockQuoteSoap;

public class Emailtest {

    public static void stockQuoteTest() {
        StockQuote stockService = new StockQuote();
        StockQuoteSoap s = stockService.getStockQuoteSoap12();
        // We don't actually need to call SOAP to demonstrate the problem
        // System.out.println("quote is "+s.getQuote("GOOG"));
    }

    public static void testMime() throws MessagingException {
        String msg = "\u0287x\u01DD\u0287 u\u028Dop \u01DDp\u1D09sdn";

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("" + msg, "utf-8");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            messageBodyPart.writeTo(os);
            String aString = new String(os.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
            System.out.println(aString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Before call to SOAP:");
            testMime();

            stockQuoteTest();

            System.out.println("After call to SOAP:");
            testMime();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Before call to SOAP:
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=CA=87x=C7=9D=CA=87 u=CA=8Dop =C7=9Dp=E1=B4=89sdn

After call to SOAP:
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

?x?? u?op ?p?sdn
```

Oh, and in case it matters, the encoded text is:

```
ʇxǝʇ uʍop ǝpᴉsdn
```

You can see where `quoted-printable` is failing to work (second call) that the 'upside down' letters which are created using normal letters show through. Investigation shows it's simply not doing `quoted-printable` at all.

## Update

This would appear to be [a bug in jax-ws](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-656) and arguably a bug in javax.mail for relying on the `text/plain` handler that happens to be in JAF rather its own. Any ideas for a work-around? (using Java 7, where is is allegedly fixed in jax-ws is not an option)

Comment: OK, why the downvote without explanatino? It's a completely replicable issue, with a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because of [this bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-656) in JAX-WS (allegedly fixed in Java 7).

JAX-WS uses JAF to introduce a `DataHandler` for type `text/plain` that does not respect the character set (i.e. `text/plain; charset="utf-8"`. When the JAX-WS class is loaded, this is used rather than the `text/plain` handler within `javax.mail`. This then uses the java platform default encoding, rather than the encoding specified.

Two possible work-arounds are:

- Upgrade to Java 7 (specifically for JAX-WS)
- Launch the application with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on the command line to set the Java default file encoding; obviously this may have other consequences